# Filling 3rd column based on value of 2nd column in data frame in R

Tags: r, if-statement, vectorization

I want to check if the 2nd column of my data frame has an empty value or not and fill a third column called "label" accordingly.

Data Frame is like this:

```
col1   col2   label
hello  there  both filled
this   that   both filled 
start  ""     col2 empty
```

I am trying this:

```
for (i in nrow(dataframe)) {

if (isTRUE(dataframe[i,c('col2')] == "") == TRUE) 
   { dataframe[i,]$label <- "both filled" }
else{
   dataframe[i,]$label <- "col2 empty" }
  }
}
```

But all I get is the same label for every row

Comment: Take a look in `?ifelse`

Comment: Amazingly, although there are [4665 questions on R ifelse](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+ifelse) or also [tag:vectorization], I can't find a direct duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `ifelse` is one solution (as mentioned by David). `ifelse` is vectorised as you can see below:

```
df$label <- ifelse( df$col2=='',  'col2_empty',  'both_filled' )
```

Output1:

```
> df
   col1  col2       label
1 hello there both_filled
2  this  that both_filled
3 start        col2_empty
```

OR a different way using regular subsetting:

```
#add col2_empty for empty second column first
df$label[df$col2==''] <- 'col2_empty'    
#add both_filled for filled second column 
df$label[!df$col2==''] <- 'both_filled'
```

Output2:

```
> df
   col1  col2       label
1 hello there both_filled
2  this  that both_filled
3 start        col2_empty
```